# Make shareable code across several Spark SBT projects

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I have some code that I want to use in different Spark projects. I'm using sbt to create the .jar file.

I saw [this idea](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/231179)

> Put the shared code into a another project that builds its own JAR
>   file, and use it in both projects.

But that post is old and also exclusively for Java... I'm wondering if there is a better way for my scenario.

Comment: The same principle applies, sbt actually uses ivy for dependency management which was originally build for java. You also need a repository such as nexus if you want to build on multiple computers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this adding in the `build.sbt` file the followings:

```
lazy val core = RootProject(file("../coreProject"))

val main = Project(id = "application", base = file(".")).dependsOn(core)
```