# How to call a file of another module in Spark Scala project

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two projects, one of them is an almost finished one (let's call it `A`). 
I'm developing the other (let's say `B`) but I've realized I need to use many files from the `A` project. To do so, I was searching and I found I could add `A` as a module of `B`, in order to automatically update the file when I do some modification on it. I'm using Intellij IDEA and I already add `A` as a module, but now I don't know how can I create an object in `B` from a class inside `A`.

Any suggestions?

(My projects are in Spark + Scala + SBT)

Answer (score 0):

Solution to your requirement is explained here
https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-create-sbt-projects-with-subprojects

The key is to create a Build.scala in main project to define the dependencies between main project and sub-project(s)

Comment: I've read the article but what I want to do is to have separately projects and use one of them as module of the other using the following: `Project Settings` -> `Modules` -> `Add` for the IntelliJ IDEA. I've tried but I couldn't use functions from the new module...

Comment: I've solved it doing the following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57549198/5081366